# How to get the JWT token via webservice

Tags: 8, csrf

After enabling the [JWT module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt) and following [Using JSON Web Tokens (JWT) to Authenticate Requests to REST Resources in Drupal 8](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/using-json-web-tokens-jwt-authenticate-requests-rest-resources-drupal-8/) on how to use it, it is working.

I know I can access the user JWT token by visiting /jwt/token. My problem is when I try to log in via web services. It returns me the following.

```
{
    "current_user": {
        "uid": "4",
        "name": "cravushedal"
    },
    "csrf_token": "OlTb7fak5ZS-r1BRiGtBh4IWLm_Z7F1xMpY3KYTGkrU",
    "logout_token": "5DiupHgr9iDxIDVmhHTI3PMX2-Shd6sjuN8hNHrHv7E"
}
```

**With postman**
In postman, after login, I receive a cookie, and with that cookie, I can access the `jwt/token` route and receive the bearer token.

But, I am using angular 5, and what I want is to access to that rout without the **cookie**, just by csrf token. Is that possible? I mean, I am trying to include it in the header, but not result. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use [Get JWT on Login module](https://www.drupal.org/project/getjwtonlogin) that I have created for the same purpose.